Kernel SHAP - Estimation of contribution function
I have been reading the online book by Christoph Molnar on Interpretable ML (link)
If we have
$$\sum_{S \subseteq M} \bigg((v(S) - (\phi_0 + \sum_{j \in S} \phi_j)\bigg)^2 K(M,S)
$$
where $S$ is set of features, $M$ is the set of features in the coalition, and $K$ is the Shapley Kernel which will weight the losses.
Molnar, in the (link), discusses how to approximate $v(S)$, the contribution function, which is defined as
$$v(S)=E[f(x)|x_S=x^*_S]$$
Molnar uses a slightly different notation in his book: $$v(S)=E[f(x)|x_j=x^*_j]$$ referring to the index $j$ in the coalition vector which I find less precise.
Molnar says

Sampling from the marginal distribution means ignoring the dependence
structure between present and absent features. KernelSHAP therefore
suffers from the same problem as all permutation-based interpretation
methods. The estimation puts too much weight on unlikely instances.
Results can become unreliable. But it is necessary to sample from the
marginal distribution. The solution would be to sample from the
conditional distribution, which changes the value function, and
therefore the game to which Shapley values are the solution. As a
result, the Shapley values have a different interpretation: For
example, a feature that might not have been used by the model at all
can have a non-zero Shapley value when the conditional sampling is
used. For the marginal game, this feature value would always get a
Shapley value of 0, because otherwise it would violate the Dummy
axiom.

I do not understand why Molnar says "necessary". I have also found sources, for example this one where they do in fact discuss the use of copula and VAEAC to estimate the conditional distribution $p(x_{\overline{S}}|x_S=x^*_S$ in
$$
v(S) = E[f(x)|x_S=x^*_S)] 
= E[f(x_{\overline{S}},x_S)|x_s=x^*_S] =
\int f(x_{\overline{S}},x^*_S)p(x_{\overline{S}}|x_S=x^*_S) dx_{\overline{S}}
$$
I understand that if you would be sampling from the marginal you would have a better approximation from a shap game where the feature is removed from the coalition. However, as Molnar itself says, using the marginal puts too much weight on unlikely values and the estimation of the contribution function becomes unreliable. Isn't the use of the marginal distribution therefore not only not necessary but ultimately incorrect?

This sampling from marginals, which is done for many explanation methods, i.e. not only for SHAP, is heatedly debated (see Hooker et.al. arguing "against", see Janzing et.al. arguing "pro").
Since there is no ground-truth for any of these methods, the question of "correctness" seems to be moot. Obviously, both approaches are possible, they just have different consequences and results. Hence, the question is not what is the "correct" approach, but which approach is the best answer to your question.
In this context, the distinction between "true to the data" and "true to the model", made by Su-In Lee et.al. seems pertinent to me. I.e. do you want to analyse your model $f$ as a function on some input domain $f:\mathscr{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ or do you want to analyse it as a random variable $f(X)$ of your data generating process? The former case is fine with marginal sampling (or, in fact, any other convenient measure on the input domain) while in the latter case, conditional expectation seems more appropriate.
As a final note, the proposed fix, using tractable distributions, copulas or even VAEs, has its own problems in real world applications. Most distributions are not tractable, their copulas are unknown and in general difficult to estimate.

See also https://github.com/christophM/interpretable-ml-book/issues/142 and https://github.com/shap/shap/issues/1098.
